# Why does an namespace in XML specify http:?

Tags: xml, wcf

Please clear up something for me.  I'm learning WCF and see a ServiceContractAttribute parameterized with Namespace = "http://www.mywebsite.com/andsoforth"

I read in another question that Namespaces are unique opaque keys.  Instead of using GUIDs they are often URLs because legitimate ones are guaranteed unique.

Why is the "http:" scheme specified with a namespace URL?  Why not just the URL?

Thanks for clarifying this.

Comment: Is this a typo? "I'm learning WCP" - did you mean WCF?

Answer (score 3):

Specifying the protocol, practically always `http://`, as part of the namespace URI is **just a convention, and a bad one at that**. (Check the [threads from July 2009 on XML-DEV](http://lists.xml.org/archives/xml-dev/200907/threads.html) to see some discussion of how XML namespaces are **badly botched on various accounts**, including the (fixable) *convention* of using URLs (instead of URNs) as URIs. Key XML people themselves are admitting XML namespaces are badly botched, but what can you do? They're here to stay.)

Why are HTTP URLs such a bad choice? Protocol colon double slash lots of letters slash directory more slashes and directory and now a final slash or rather not? Because one trailing slash does make a difference.

What should it have been like? Well, DNS, or Java namespaces. Does the job without confusing people.

Here's a practical recommendation. Make your life easier by choosing easy namespaces. [Take a look at URNs](http://www.jclark.com/xml/xmlns.htm), they're pretty close to DNS and Java.

Comment: Thanks for the URN reference.  I couldn't read it because it was so poorly written, but the Wikipedia article clarified it for me.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in that the namespace name (or URI) is only a unique identifier to define the namespace.  For example, http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml does not actually contain the schema for XHTML but rather a human readable document.  The identifier is merely a URI.

And the protocol is part of the definition for a URI.  For example if I create a folder and call it "directory.com", I can have file://directory.com/file resolving perfectly on my local machine.  However it will be a completely different resource than what is hosted at http://directory.com/file.  The computer needs the protocol to know which one I want.

In other words, we've chosen URIs to uniquely define namespaces.  And protocol is an important part of a URI to separate resources.

It is theoretically valid to have two namespaces with two separate protocols to mean two different things.  Like many things, it is probably a bad idea because of the confusion it would cause, but it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think one of the reasons http:// is used in namespace names is that there has always been a section of the community who thought that one day it would be possible to type a namespace name into a web browser and get back a definition of what the namespace means. There's even a standard for doing that, called RDDL, and a few people follow it. Others are content that the URL should resolve to some human-readable information about the namespace. Try for example typing http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema into your browser.

However, it's true that there is no requirement that a namespace URI should resolve to anything, and there is no useful purpose today for software to try to dereference the URL (if indeed it is a URL), and I suspect there never will be.

Comment: Very cool, Michael. I haven't seen any mention RDDL in years.

Answer (score 0):

Some good answers already. Here's an additional perspective. An XML namespace is in fact a URI, not restricted to being a URL. Sometimes people use URLs as a way of indicating where metadata might be available, but usually that's not the case. The one aspect that is often used is that companies have own an Internet domain, and typically express that domain in a URL, so http://www.mycompany.com/... is a way of creating company-specific URIs.

In most cases, I prefer to make the it clear that I am using a URN, which is a URI that is not a URL. I even add a prefix to the value to make it clear that is what I am doing. Something like this" urn:mycompany.com/schemas/services/foo/bar/20111119.